# Jquery ajax request error callback is called instead of success even after response recieved from server

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery ajax function to get some content from my webservice. Response from the server is received but every time error callback is called instead of success callback.

And this error is returned in xhr.error:

```
function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}
```

Here is the screenshot of response from server:

[image: error pic]

and here is the code I am using to make the request:

```
function abcdef()
{
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.61.129:8000/get-yt-access-token/",
type: "GET",
contentType:"application/json",
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("its error! " + xhr.error);
    },
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: we want errorThrown, not xhr.error. xhr.error is a function.

Comment: you sure you web service is sending back a json, copy paste the response from the console (not `alert(data)`)

Comment: @mikakun well, he didn't specify that the server must return json. He just specified that he was sending json (but he never actually sent json)

Comment: You're performing a CORS request. is your webservice setup to correctly handle CORS requests?

Comment: `contentType:"application/json",` your ajax call expect a json response - copy paste the response from the console (not alert(data))

Comment: @mikakun No, that's not at all what that parameter does. You're thinking of the dataType parameter.

Comment: errorThrown is an empty string i have already checked.

Comment: Go to the console. Do you see any red text? i expect to see something similar to ACCESS DENIDED DUE TO SAME-ORIGIN POLICY

Comment: here is the screenshot of console: ![console](http://i.imgur.com/mD9RG9i.png)

Comment: see how the request is an *"OPTIONS"* request rather than a *"GET"* request? the *"OPTIONS"* response should NOT be returning JSON. your server isn't responding correctly to this request.

Comment: @kevinB no there is no error like that and i think if it is the issue regarding CORS then server should not send any response but i am getting the desired response on firebug just not able to access in javascript and getting error callback executed instead.

Comment: right, but the fact still remains, it's an OPTIONS request and not a GET request. OPTIONS requests happen when a CORS request is sent. The OPTIONS request should have been followed up with a GET request that returns the json.

Comment: looking mechanically, my bad, sorry for waste of bytes

Comment: @kevinB yeah you was right, it was a CORS issue at the end! solved it! run both webservice and webpage from same server and problem was solved. Thanks everyone!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a CORS issue at the end! solved it! run both webservice and webpage from same server and problem was solved.